# Passing blocks for methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I would like to pass in different blocks into a method. The method would subsequently use the passed in block as parameter to dispatch_async.

I have my block declared like this:

```
typedef int (^ComputationBlock)(int);
```

The class method that accepts the block is implemented as:

```
- (void)doSomething:(int)limit withBlock:(ComputationBlock)block;
{

 dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

   // typical in-lined block for dispatch_async:  
 dispatch_async(queue, ^{
      // do some work here
 });

 // I want to pass in the block as the 2nd parameter to dispatch_async
 // but the compiler will warn me of a type mismatch unless I cast
 // the block like:
 dispatch_async(queue, (dispatch_block_t)block);    
}

@end
```

Is it okay to typecast the '`block`' parameter as `dispatch_block_t`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, that's not cool to do -- the block passed to dispatch_async needs to take no parameters and return nothing. Casting your ComputationBlock to that would be a Bad Idea (it's not nice to fool mother nature).

Simply wrap your block that you want to call inside one of the right type:

```
 dispatch_async(queue, ^{ block(0); } );
```

(note that you also need to supply a parameter to your ComputationBlock when you invoke it.)

Comment: N.B. "ComputationBlock" doesn't match dispatch_block_t in its return-type as well: should be void, actually is int! Aside: "it's not nice to fool mother nature" \*smile\*

Answer (score 4):

It may compile, but it won't work.  `dispatch_block_t` blocks must not take any arguments and must not have a return value.

Answer (score 0):

Pass value using __block

> __block int backValue;

it can modify in block